# Running python scripts in Next.js

Tags: python, reactjs, scikit-learn, next.js

Is it possible to call a python script to run server-side by Next.js? I am trying to set up a way to call some python packages I have already developed to be run on my website that is built via React.js + Next.js. I'm hoping to integrate some sklearn methods.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**On Server Start**

If you want to run the script on Next.js server startup and create a script inside the package.json and run it on before `npm start`

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "sh ./make-coffee.sh",
  "start": "next start"
},
```

**From Node.js**

If you want to run the script from Node.js(Next.js) code use Child process [Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('"file/test.sh" arg1 arg2');
```

**REST API**

Create REST API for python script and call from next.js server

Answer (score 3):

From a Node.js backend API route you can use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) package built into Node to spawn a process that runs a Python script. You can  access the standard output the `stdout` attribute on the spawned process, but please note this will only return printed data. This is likely to be unsafe, as you or a library could accidentally call a print statement that you're not looking for. To recieve data from the Python script, at the end of the execution, you can print json data which can then be parsed in JavaScript.

I would only recommend doing this if this is exactly what you're looking for, otherwise there is probably a better alternative, like building the backend in Python to begin with and not needing to hacking-ly move the data to JavaScript.

```
//pages/api

const {spawn} = require('child_process');

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    let python = spawn('python', ['python/hello.py']);
    let dataToSend = '';

    for await (const data of python.stdout){
      //console.log(data.toString());
      dataToSend += data.toString()
    }
  return res.status(200).json({ message: dataToSend})
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Honestly when I wrote this is a wild hacky rabbit hole.... 

What you would be better to do is setup a API as a serverless function to just run your python scripts on something like Flask or FastAPI and then just talk to the external api by enabling CORS

Alternatively, dropping Next.js backend replacing the backend with Flask or Fast API and just serve static html from npm run build.